# How do I add characters to RegEx results?

Tags: regex

I am not a programmer but I am having to use RegEx for a particular purpose.  How do I add specific characters to what is being returned from RegEx?

For example, if I have a list as follows:

```
XYZ ABC 123
```

How do I use RegEx to add something specific to the end of each?  For example, if I want all three to end with `.com` for example?

Comment: What programming language are you doing this in? Or are you using an editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text?

Comment: That's not what regex is. Regex (regular *expressions*) are just *expressions* - they express how your string looks (and what to match) but they do not do replacement. Most regex implementations do have a `.replace` method though, so with this you could replace `([^\s]+)` with `$1.com` (some use `\1.com`).

Comment: You can only "use regex" to *see what matches your expression*. You cannot add something to 'the result' without changing the expression (and it still must match).

Comment: Welcome to SO ! From today am not doing free homework. So you will have to show some effort to solve it. Otherwise you will gather nothing but down votes.

Comment: Yes, @noob is not available from today onward. So please show some effort.

Comment: What part of of "I am not a programmer" did you not understand?  Thank you Druzion and h2oooooo and Rad Lexus for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script, replacing `XYZ abc 123` with your full list:

`echo "XYZ abc 123" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1.com/g'`

Explanation:

- `s/` Starts a substitution regex
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` Capture at least one alphanumeric
- `/` End regex
- `\1.com` replaces the capture with itself plus adds `.com`
- `/g` Global modifier (for all matches)

Without knowing *which* regex engine you want to use, there are many other ways to do this. In the future, please give more information.